# Positive Lookahead and negative lookbehind in regex

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I'm trying to figure out how to search for a phrase containing keyword and associated value

Suppose I have the following sentences :

1. Keyword for server is abc
2. abc is keyword for server
3. keyword needs to be reset
4. change keyword for server

I should get abc in case of 1 & 2, but should not get any result in case of 3&4.

I am using plain vanilla regex for 2
`r'\w+\s\bis\s\bthe\s\b\keyword'`, and this seems to work fine. But I am looking for a more general regex for all 4 cases.

Any suggestion?

Comment: will `is` going to be there either before or after the keyword as you shown with `abc` example. `abc` has 'is` either before or after it in 1 and 2. Trying to see if there is anything that gives us the pattern required

Comment: The regular expression you give as matching `2` doesn't match it, (i) your sentence `2` doesn't contain the word `the`, (ii) you have included a backslash "\" in front of the letter "`k`" of "`keyword`", Python would treat this as a syntax error.

Comment: @JBone, 'is' may or may not be there....the sentence could be 'keyword for server abc'

Comment: Didn't realize is may not be there, so I deleted my answer. 
Do the sentences you want to match follow any other rule that just having 'keyword' in them ?

Comment: Explain why `\babc\b` is inadequate.

Comment: abc is just example of one of many values. Presence of keyword is imp

Comment: @Charles keyword will be associated with a value in most of the instances such that - keyword for server abc, keyword is xyz, abc is keyword etc. There are also instances where keyword will be present but not in the context of having a value. Few examples ..reset the keyword, keyword is found, keyword was set etc. I should be able to identify the instances which have keyword and value as True positive and ones with no value associated as False Positive

Comment: If you have a list of everything that keyword can come with (so `abc` or `xyd` or whatever, as well as `found`, `set`...) you may be able to this with a regex. But it would probably be one of the worst ways to do it.
If you don't have or a recognizable  pattern, or such a list, you won't be able to do it with a regex.